# What problems would I face setting up an off-line network to support 50+ devices to view a php page?

Tags: wireless-networking, xampp, offline-files

Looking to assist a friend in creating an offline network to support 50-90 devices for a show. I'll be using wampp to host a few php/js/hmtl files on my laptop that an offline router will allow these devices to connect to.
There will be a php script set up to play a sound at a set time on all these devices. 
Q 
Is there a way replicate the scenario to test whether the router can handle the all these connections at once?

What other problems would i need to look out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to make sure that you use a more enterprise grade Access Point (AP) and not use a home router, enterprise grade Access Points (Ruckus, Cisco, AeroHive etc...) are built and tested for your deployment requirements.  The home routers (not all routers but most) are usually tuned to support 10 simultaneous devices and no more than that.  You may want to consider having 2-3 Access points deployed on different channels, this will greatly reduce interference and noise and will allow for less devices per AP which will free up bandwidth.  You may want to consider deploying on 5GHz rather than 2.4GHz depending on your device capability, 5GHZ has more channels to choose from than 2.4GHz.  Since WiFi is a shared medium, you may want to consider getting the bandwidth used by 1 device and multiplying that by 50-90 devices, you can use the free version of [PRTG](https://www.paessler.com/download/prtg-download) for that.  You may want to use PRTG during your show to monitor your Wireless APs and Wireless traffic.  For example if your required bandwidth per device is 3Mbps (3Mbps x 90devices = 270Mbps), you'll have to plan to provide for 270Mbps of bandwidth.  Your devices may not all TX/RX at the same time, but it's good practice to know your bandwidth requirements.  You may also have to ensure that your DHCP server is configured with a pool that provides 90-100 address.  There is a way to test large number of clients with a test tool, however it is a very expensive proposition. 
 The tool is provided by Ixia and it called Veriwave. Anyway, good luck...

Comment: thank you for that, we'll test it with a home router and then look into getting a ruckus (i know they're are good). We're trying to set it up in a way where the webpage is deployed and remains on standby on their devices. This way there wont be a need for a constant connection. We should be having a test session soon to try this out. Regards.